# Can update two tables using join operation in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my web application using asp.net I have a gridview with edit button. This gridview is created by joining two tables. I need to update those two tables when I click those edit button..
My gridview consists 3fields- name,nric,and status.where the name and nric from table 1 and status from table2. How will be the query to update both tables ?
Please help

```
 protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
}
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    TextBox id = (TextBox)row.FindControl("s_id");
    TextBox name = (TextBox)row.FindControl("s_name");
    TextBox nric = (TextBox)row.FindControl("s_nric");
    TextBox status = (TextBox)row.FindControl("s_status");
    SqlConnection con = obj.getcon(); 
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update e.student_details ,f.student_vs_testsession_details  set e.student_id='" + id.Text+ "',e.student_name='" + name.Text + "',e.student_nric='" + nric.Text + "',f.testsession_status='" + status.Text + "' where e.student_id=f.student_id", con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();


}
```

Comment: what have you tried so far. How are you binding gridview. put some code here.

Comment: You can help Us by posting what you've tried, what you actually want and some useful code.

Answer (score 0):

Your join query will be same as it is. [According to your DB Table structure, which you have not specified.] For Edit operation in GridView have following things:

**You have to deal with 3 events :**

`RowEditing`, `RowCancelingEdit`,`RowUpdating`

**Following is the code:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
   GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

}


protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = true;
   GridView1.EditIndex = -1;

}

protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

   TextBox txtProductName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtProductName");
   TextBox txtUnitPrice = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtUnitPrice");

   //From here you can fire Update query on database.

}
```

**Reference Link:**

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1993146

Hope its helpful.

Comment: can you explain what is this means  " TextBox txtProductName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtProductName"); "

Comment: Yes, txtProductName is object of textbox created, which holds the value of item in the row for which you have clicked edit button.

Comment: Sir, My gridview consists 3fields- name,nric,and status.where the name and nric from table 1 and status from table2. How will be the query to update both tables ?

Comment: update table1,table2 set table1.name=@name,table1.nric=@nric,table2.status=@status where table1.pkField=table2.pkField

Comment: table1's pk must be table2's fk, you will have to deal with matching columns in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Divya , This can be possible . When you click on update button that time your gird variable pass updated data to database but here you need to fire to different update statement. let me know if you have further query.... Just try this....!

Comment: Hello Divya , I am database guy so I don't have more experienced with application code. But one thing is sure that you can not update more than one table using one single update statement for that you have to execute different update statement . Now pass relevant variable to relevant update statement . let me know for further query . Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

@Divya Hari: You can achieve this task by store procedure.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
 {
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    TextBox txtName = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtName");
    TextBox txtstatus = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtstatus");

    //     From here you can fire Update query on database.
    // Here you write code for store procedure.


 }
```

Store Procedure.

```
 in SP you need to write update query for both table. Something like this.


 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateBothTable 
    @ID int,
    @Name varchar(50),
    @Status varchar(10)
 AS
 BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

     -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Update table1 set Name=@Name where ID=@ID

    Update Table2 set Status=@Status where ID=@ID


 END
 GO
```

Hope this will help you....:)

Comment: thankyou sir..but is there any need to connect txtname with @Name ?

Comment: Yes you have to pass parameter to the store procedure variable @Name

Comment: whatever you try just put your code here i'll do changes in that and give you full code. This is just a sample code. how you achieve the task.

Comment: sir,how to call this stored procedure in c#asp.net ?

Comment: Sorry yesterday m not online i just review your code and give it to you and ya you can also contact me on my mail id vyas100688@gmail.com

Comment: This way you can call store procedure

' SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC-012;Initial Catalog=Inventory;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "GetCustomer";// name of storeprocedure.
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet dsSample = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dsSample);
            Session["dsSample"] = dsSample;'